# DX12) Even though they are ComPtr, Live Objects apears When Process Terminated

Tags: com, directx-12, dxgi

I'm making a ray tracing DX12 renderer, but ComPtr doesn't seem to release properly when I exit the process.(Press the x button to exit the window, or exit via WM_CLOSE or WM_DESTROY)

They are ComPtr and I think I didn't do anything about copying or referencing...

I don't know what's wrong with my code.

here's error codes :

```
D3D12 WARNING: Live ID3D12Device at 0x000001FB2DBFEF60, Refcount: 15 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #274: LIVE_DEVICE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12CommandQueue at 0x000001FB35FA1520, Name: Unnamed ID3D12CommandQueue: Type=Direct, UniqueId=0x4d33f1f, Refcount: 7, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #570: LIVE_COMMANDQUEUE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live IDXGISwapChain at 0x000001FB360DA1D0, Refcount: 2 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #275: LIVE_SWAPCHAIN]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12LifetimeTracker at 0x000001FB360DC050, Refcount: 2, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #1164: LIVE_LIFETIMETRACKER]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Fence at 0x000001FB360DC2C0, Name: Internal DXGI Fence, Refcount: 1, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #580: LIVE_MONITOREDFENCE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12CommandAllocator at 0x000001FB360E0530, Name: Internal DXGI CommandAllocator, Refcount: 1, IntRef: 2 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #571: LIVE_COMMANDALLOCATOR]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12GraphicsCommandList at 0x000001FB360E0DF0, Name: Internal DXGI CommandList, Refcount: 1, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #573: LIVE_COMMANDLIST12]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Resource at 0x000001FB361455B0, Name: Unnamed Committed ID3D12Resource: Format=R8G8B8A8_UNORM, Dimension=Texture2D, Width=1920, Height=1080, ArraySize: 1, MipLevels=1, UniqueId=0x4d33f39, Refcount: 2, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #575: LIVE_RESOURCE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Resource at 0x000001FB36146190, Name: Unnamed Committed ID3D12Resource: Format=R8G8B8A8_UNORM, Dimension=Texture2D, Width=1920, Height=1080, ArraySize: 1, MipLevels=1, UniqueId=0x4d33f3c, Refcount: 2, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #575: LIVE_RESOURCE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Fence at 0x000001FB36146D70, Refcount: 1, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #580: LIVE_MONITOREDFENCE]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12DescriptorHeap at 0x000001FB3614A120, Name: Unnamed ID3D12DescriptorHeap: Type=RTVNumDescriptors=2, UniqueId=0x4d33f70, Refcount: 1, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #576: LIVE_DESCRIPTORHEAP]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12CommandAllocator at 0x000001FB3614CFF0, Refcount: 1, IntRef: 2 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #571: LIVE_COMMANDALLOCATOR]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12GraphicsCommandList at 0x000001FB3614D8B0, Name: Unnamed ID3D12GraphicsCommandList: Type=Direct, UniqueId=0x4d33f75, Refcount: 1, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #573: LIVE_COMMANDLIST12]
D3D12 WARNING:  Live ID3D12Fence at 0x000001FB361ACAD0, Refcount: 1, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #580: LIVE_MONITOREDFENCE]
```

All of them is defined with ComPtr, and program is currently just initializing them with D3D12 APIs.

and here's my github repository:
https://github.com/kcjsend2/Chulsu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reporting live objects before the destructors for your members have been invoked. This is how I would do it:

```
inline void ReportLiveObjects()
{
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGIDebug1> dxgi_debug;
    if (SUCCEEDED(DXGIGetDebugInterface1(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(dxgi_debug.GetAddressOf()))))
    {
            dxgi_debug->ReportLiveObjects(DXGI_DEBUG_ALL, DXGI_DEBUG_RLO_FLAGS(DXGI_DEBUG_RLO_DETAIL | DXGI_DEBUG_RLO_IGNORE_INTERNAL));
    }
}
```

and then call this function after the your renderer class destructor has finished, for example using atexit:

```
std::atexit(ReportLiveObjects); //you can register this in the constructor for example
```

Alternative to `atexit` would be to have an object such as `LiveObjectsReporter` whose destructor would call `ReportLiveObjects` which you would place above all your members so it's destructor gets called last:

```
class Renderer
{
    ...
private:
    LiveObjectReporter reporter;
    ComPtr<ID3D12Device> device;
    //etc
};

struct LiveObjectReporter
{
    ~LiveObjectReporter()
    {
        ReportLiveObjects();
    }
};
```

EDIT:

The reason it's showing live objects is because you actually have live device, not because the method I showed you is wrong. In your `DX12Renderer::CreateDevice` you are calling `QueryInterface` which increases reference count (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/queryinterface?view=msvc-170)). Just write it

```
 ID3D12Device* allocatorDevice = pDevice.Get();
```

or call `Release` on your `allocatorDevice`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I activated  D3D12DebugLayer, So I can see there's LiveObject when Process terminated.(it shows me simple report) There's exact same number of Live Object with Standard report but RefCount is zero...

Comment: @Hansole_Jeong You sure you passed D3D12_RLDO_IGNORE_INTERNAL?

Comment: Yeap. I checked it twice.

Comment: Can you update your github with those changes?

Comment: Repo is already Updated. I passed that flag when I initiate DX12Renderer

Comment: @Hansole_Jeong the only place I see it is in destructor? So we are back at what I wrote in the answer, unless I misunderstood you

Comment: Oh you are right... I will try your answer then.

Comment: I tried your method, and it partially works. in standard report(by ReportLiveObjects method) there's only one Live Object, ID3D12Device. (I still don't figure out why it's still there...) but in simple report, by ID3D12Debug, there's eight Live Obejcts with RefCount is 0 and one Live Object with RefCount is one (I think this is Device)... I still have fundamental problem - there's live objects.

Comment: This actually works! Accepted answer.

Comment: I think I got confused because D3D12MA Document says it release what allocator got (or I misunderstood that).

Comment: Internally it will copy the passed pointer and call AddRef too.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is that you are relying on the implicit order of destruction of the variables, and you have some of device child objects listed *before* you have your device variable listed.

In your class you have:

```
    ComPtr<ID3D12GraphicsCommandList4> mD3dCmdList;
    ComPtr<ID3D12CommandAllocator> mCmdAllocator;

    ComPtr<IDXGIFactory4> mDxgiFactory;
    ComPtr<ID3D12Device5> mD3dDevice;

    D3D12MA::Allocator* mMemAllocator = NULL;

    ComPtr<ID3D12CommandQueue> mCommandQueue;
    ComPtr<ID3D12CommandAllocator> mCommandAllocator;
```

If you look at my DX12 DeviceResource [.h](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/main/d3d12game_win32_dr/DeviceResources.h) / [.cpp](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/main/d3d12game_win32_dr/DeviceResources.cpp) implementation, you'll see I have:

```
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D12Device>                m_d3dDevice;
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D12GraphicsCommandList>   m_commandList;
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D12CommandQueue>          m_commandQueue;
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D12CommandAllocator>      m_commandAllocators[MAX_BACK_BUFFER_COUNT];

        // Swap chain objects.
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGIFactory4>               m_dxgiFactory;
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain3>             m_swapChain;
```

In my case, device is "first" in the variable decalaration, so its "last" to be destructed.

Comment: I tried it, but everything is same... same messages and all that warnings.

Comment: The NVIDIA [link] https://developer.nvidia.com/rtx/raytracing/dxr/dx12-raytracing-tutorial-part-1 (DXR _HelloWorld_) sample suffers from the same problem in that temporary scratch buffers declared as COM pointers are not destroyed when the part of the code they are in falls out of scope. It was necessary to call `Release()` to destroy the ID3D12Resources instead.

Comment: Then Should I release all that Interfaces Manually on Destructor? in Past Project, this works not that bad actually. in that project, every allocation goes well with ComPtr... Release all that ID3D12Resources manually sounds like terrible.